# Custom UITableViewCells UITextField strong or weak reference?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting

I'm pragmatically setting up a tableview with uitextfields, uisegmentedcontrols, etc.

Here's an example

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //NSLog(@"creating a new %@", CellIdentifier);

    if([CellIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ID"]) {

       UITextField *newTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 5, 215, 34)];
        self.idField = newTextField;
        [cell addSubview:self.idField];

    }
}
```

I am creating properties for all of these text fields and assigning them to the newly created fields as you can see.

My question is should I be using (nonatomic, strong) or (nonatomic, weak) ?

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UITextField *idField;
//Or
@property(nonatomic, strong) UITextField *idField;
```

Comment: idField can only be one text field at a time. are you trying to store a reference in your property to the most recently created text field? what are you ultimately trying to achieve? if your intent is to keep references to all of the text fields that you create, this isn't doing it.

Comment: I have a idField, upcField, Alias Field, Description field, etc. I did this so that I could read the text field. i.e. [self.idField.text] It works fine as is right now. I'm just wondering if I should use strong or weak

Answer (score 0):

You should not create member variables for those textFields at all.. For what do you need a second textField? Perhaps another Cell Style is enough for your purpose? E.g. `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` or `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`?

But if you need a custom one, just assign it a tag (e.g. the row of the tableViewCell) and retrieve it afterwards via `viewWithTag:`. If you want direct access think of a custom UITableViewCell subclass.

To give a direct answer to your question: Probably a weak reference would be enough here, since the textField is added on a cell, which will not get deallocated at any time (since it will be reused).

Comment: Actually it won't be reused since there is only 1 of these kinds of cells... it will however be removed if the user scrolls. I have many different tableviewcells with different textfields, segmented controls, imageviews, etc. But I need to be able to have access to each them.

Comment: and when the user scrolls back, it appears again, right? so it gets reused. (at the same spot and for the same content, but still, it gets reused). means: it wont get deallocated at any point, before the table gets deallocated.

Comment: Only if I have enough memory... It seems sometimes (like when I load an image) these cells do indeed get deallocated and I have to recreate them. Thus I store their contents somewhere else and when they get recreated I load from the stored contents. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I disagree with you. :) You appear to be  more knowledgeable than me so please fill me in ;)

Comment: You are right, they may get deallocated if memory is getting low. But especially then, you SHOULD let it deallocate the whole cell - meaning also your textFields. So still, as I said in the answer, you should use tags or custom cell subclasses to access your textfields. (and create a new textField, if needed - what you are doing already anyway with the code posted above)